# Modification of a submartingale $(M_t)_{t}$ that is determined by rational limits approaching from the right

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, filtrations

Suppose $(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a submartingale (on a complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$) with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ that satisfies the usual conditions.

$(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a submartingale means: $\forall s \le t \in [a,b]$, $$E[M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] \ge M_s \qquad a.s.,$$
where $E [\cdot \mid \mathcal{F}_s]$ denotes conditional expectation given $\mathcal{F}_s$.

The filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ satisfies the usual conditions means: [i] $P$-null sets belong to $\mathcal{F}_0$, and [ii] $\forall t \in [0,\infty)$, $$\mathcal{F}_t = \bigcap_{s > t} \mathcal{F}_s.$$

Also, let the process $(S_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ be given by $$S_t := \lim_{\mathbb{Q} \ni r \to t^{+}} M_r,$$
where the term $\lim_{\mathbb{Q} \ni r \to t^{+}}$ means that $r$ are rational numbers that approaches to $t$ from the right.

---

**Question**: given that the map $t \mapsto E[M_t]$ is right continuous, how can I show that $(S_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a modification of $(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$?

($(S_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a modification of $(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ means that $P (S_t = M_t) = 1$.)

---

This is part of Lemma 1.4.2 of the book "Multiparameter Resources:
An Introduction to Random Fields" by Davar Khoshnevisan. I couldn't figure out the proof. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I will remove my answer (temporarily, I hope) since there is some mess.

Comment: @ GGYYD : I suggest that you take a look at "Theorem 3.13" in the first chapter "Martinagles, Stopping Times and Filtrations" of the book of Karatzas and Shreve "Bronwian Motion ans Stochastic Calculus". Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge : OK. Thanks a lot.